# Does a superconducting coil need a minimum amount of electric current to be a superconducting magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, superconductivity

I'm not about that for a tiny amount of Cooper electrons perhaps we can't measure the magnetic field. I suppose that it needs some influental electric current below which the coil isn't a superfluid magnet . This I conclude from the fact that accelerated electron has to radiate photons which can not be in the case of a superconducting magnet. This kind of electromagnet does not lose energy. Does exist a minimum current below which the coil isn't a superconducting magnet?

Comment: The question contained in the title makes an implication in direct contradiction with the implication made in the text. I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @DanielSank A superconducting coil is a device which can be a under some circumstances a superconducting magnet

Comment: I agree with that statement. Is there a question?

Comment: @DanielSank Added the question explizit